# How to use netty-socketio API in Tomcat? Getting /socket.io/socket.io.js 404 (Not Found)

Tags: socket.io

Please let me know the psuedo code to use Netty Socketio API in Tomact server.

I am trying to start the Netty's SocketIOServer by adding following code in the init() method of my HttpServlet in web application:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.setHostname("localhost");
config.setPort(81);
SocketIOServer server = new SocketIOServer(config);
server.start();
```

============================

But I am getting the following error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) GET http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1404288173776-3 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

My Client java script code (HTML) in this WAR file is as follows:

```
<script> 
var socket = io(http://localhost:8080/DemoApp/DemoServlet);
socket.on('event', function() {...some logic here....});
</script>
```

I am using Tomcat 7.0.62 version and Netty API 4.0 version

let me know the pseudo code to start Netty's SocketIOServer in Tomcat for websocket communication between client and server. I have to push the data from server to client code. Kindly reply me earliest possible

Thanks,